# Accessing JavaScript Object property dynamically during useState update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have useState variable defined as such

```
 const [queryBuilder, setQueryBuilder] = useState({location: [], metric: [], datetime: [], statistics: []})
```

then I have a function which should be able to set individual property back to empty array []. Here I ran into problem and I tried several ways but none worked, for example.

```
const clearCategory = (e, category) => {
    setQueryBuilder(prev => { return {...prev, prev[category]: []}})
}
```

this wont work, but I try to access property via previous object and bracket notation (i also tried dot notation).

Normally I can access dynamically like so

```
queryBuilder[category]
```

but during useState hook I cant, how do I accomplish this ?

And, writing

```
setQueryBuilder(prev => {return {...prev, category: []}})
```

will just create a new property named category with an empty array

Comment: `{ ...prev, [category]: [] }`

Comment: @Lennholm thank you! Takeaway is then that with ...prev Im already accessing the object so I can put directly brackets and variable. If you care to make an answer out of your comment I will accept it

Comment: Alright, answer posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should use here is a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names), which is a feature introduced in ECMAScript 2015. For your example it will look like this:

```
{ ...prev, [category]: [] }
```

Note that the computed property itself doesn't reference your `prev` object and it's technically unrelated to it. It's simply a unique member of the object that overwrites any property with the same name from the `prev` object since it's being defined **after** `prev` was spread into the object.